# How can I retrieve the data from Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: node.js, postman, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

I am new using blockchain and node.js. How can I retrieve the data from ethereum blockchain using node get method.

Is it possible to retrieve the original saved data?

Comment: You need to read two articles.
[1](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)
And [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It is a broad question to ask . First you need to give a try to code

Comment: I have no idea so only ask that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Web3 API documentation, the way to retrieve a contract instance and to call a method is:

**1. Contract Definition**

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
```

**2. Get the instance of the contract at the address**

```
var myContractInstance = MyContract .at('0x**********');
```

**3. Execute a call**

```
var owner = myContractInstance .owner.call();
```

**Full code:**

```
var abi = [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    }
  ];


var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract .at('0xa07ddaff6d8b7aabf91ac6f82bf89455eb9784f4');

// call constant function (synchronous way)
var owner = myContractInstance .owner.call();

console.log("owner="+owner);
```

**Works fine:**

```
owner=0x13a0674c16f6a5789bff26188c63422a764d9a39
```